# How to create a function in PostgreSQL that checks for datatype compatability

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, types

I am writing a program that skips bad loading files instead of breaking the whole process. Part of the process should check for datatype compatibility of input data and target table datatype. A function that checks for this in PostgreSQL would be extremely helpful. Below I have written a function that should do that; however, it fails every time regardless of input.

```
create or replace function is_type(d varchar, t varchar) returns boolean as $$
begin
  perform d::t;
  return true;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


select is_type('cats', 'varchar(2)');
```

In this example, 'cats' is 4 chars so varchar(2) would NOT be a compatible datatype. Basically, any datatype that would fail an insert should cause the function to fail. This should also work for date, integer, etc.

Comment: Actually it is compatible per [Character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html): "If one explicitly casts a value to character varying(n) or character(n), then an over-length value will be truncated to n characters without raising an error. (This too is required by the SQL standard.)" So: `select 'cats'::varchar(2); ca`. As to why it fails all the time, you are doing: `select 'cats'::'varchar(2)'; ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'varchar(2)'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple modified version of your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.is_type(d character varying, t regtype)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
  RAISE NOTICE 'TYPE  %', t;
  execute 'select cast(' || quote_literal(d) ||' as ' || t || ')' ;
  return true;
exception when others then
  return false;
end;
$function$
;

select is_type('cats', 'varchar(2)');
NOTICE:  TYPE  character varying
 is_type 
---------
 t
(1 row)

select is_type('cats', 'numeric');
NOTICE:  TYPE  numeric
 is_type 
---------
 f
(1 row)
```